# joining matrices into an array

Tags: r, matrix

I have several matrices that i would like to join them into an array as follows:

```
> mat1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

> mat2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

> mat3
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   13   15   17
[2,]   14   16   18
```

I have tried this:

```
dime=dim(mat1)
Array=array(mat1, mat2,mat3,dim(dime))
```

With the following error:

```
Error in array(mat1, mat2, mat3, dim(dime)) : 
  unused argument(s) (dim(dime))
```

What could i be doing wrong?

Comment: How do you want them to be joined? What is the final dimensions of your desired array.

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  What is the end array trying to look like?

Comment: the final array is supposed to 2 rows and 9 columns. then i will use the apply function to pick the highest value in each cell so than i only have a 2 by 3 matrix but only having the highest values in each cell.

Comment: @jonestats - that's almost a separate question. If you use Gavin's original answer, you could do `final <- array(c(mat1, mat2, mat3), dim = c(2,3,3)); apply(final,1:2,max);` to get the highest value in each cell across the 3 matrices.

Comment: @thelatemail, yes you're right, Gavin's answer solves my problem including the apply part you added. Thanks

Comment: @thelatemail, in the apply(final,1:2,max) code, what does the 1:2 mean?

Comment: @jonestats in this case it means operate over dimensions 1 *and* 2 (the rows and columns) of the new array. in other words it finds the maximum value of each matrix slice in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update:

From the comment it appears that all that is required is to `cbind` the three matrices:

```
> cbind(mat1, mat2, mat3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    3    5    1    3    5    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6    2    4    6    2    4    6
```

I suppose that if you have a lot of these, it would make sense to arrange for them to held in a list and then use `do.call` to `cbind` them together:

```
mlist <- list(mat1, mat2, mat3) ## simulate matrices stored as a list

## cbind them via a `do.call` call
do.call(cbind, mlist)
```

which yields

```
> do.call(cbind, mlist)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    3    5    1    3    5    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6    2    4    6    2    4    6
```

### Original

It isn't really very clear how you want the matrices to be arrange in the array. If you mean to stack the matrices like a pile of papers, with each leaf of paper a matrix, then we can simply concatenate the matrices into a single vector with `c` and then pass that to `array` with an appropriate `dim` argument. E.g.

```
> mat1 <- mat2 <- mat3 <- matrix(1:6, ncol = 3)
> array(c(mat1, mat2, mat3), dim = c(2,3,3))
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
```

Comment: @thelatemail, what does the 1:2 in the apply(final,1:2,max) mean?