# How to generate matrices directely into an array with a function?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I have a formula that creates matrices. Later with every single matrix of the set I have to do some time consuming stuff. So far, I'm bundling these matrices into a list with `lapply()`. Now, I assume operating with an array of matrices would be much faster. The thing is, I don't know how to let the matirices be generated into an array as with `lapply()`.

I give you this example:

```
# matrix generating function
mxSim <- function(X, n) {
  mx = matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = 3, 
              dimnames = list(NULL, c("d", "alpha", "beta")))
  mx[,1] = rbinom(n, 1, .375)
  mx[,2] = rnorm(n, 0, 2)
  mx[,3] = .42 * rnorm(n, 0, 6)
  return(mx)
}

# bundle matrices together
mx.lst <- lapply(1:1e1, mxSim, n = 1e4)

# some stuff to be done after, like e. g.:
lapply(mx.lst, function(m) lm(d ~ alpha + beta, as.data.frame(m)))
```

Could anybody give me some advise how to do this with an array?

I've been looking into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15779641/6574038) answer, but for it the matrices have to be already generated, and I only could help me by listing them before again.

Comment: I don't know either... but I would recommend you to go parallel (packages `snowfall` and/or `foreach`)

Comment: I don't know if I agree with your assumption that an array of matrices would be faster than a list of matrices. If you are apply a function to every matrix in a set of matrices, you can introduce parralelization directly upon the list. Doing so on an array is *much* more difficult.

Comment: I assume it's the same thing as with data.frames--because everything is numeric and has the same dimensions I use matrices. Now I have matrices with all the same dimensions and use a list again (which I consider to be kinda 3D-data.frame).

Comment: `sapply(mx.lst, function(m) lm(d ~ alpha + beta, as.data.frame(m)))`. Note: you are not using the matrices inside the anonymous function `sapply` calls, the elements of `mx.lst` would be named `i`, and this is not used. I have changed this and I have also changed the name of these elements to `m` because I believe in names easier to understand. (`i` rhymes with index, not with `matrix`.)

Comment: I also believe that in this particular case you should use `lapply` not `sapply`. The objects returned by `lm` are complex objects and so the appropriate structure to hold them is a `list` as returned by `lapply`.

Comment: Sure. Put whatever you want in the array/list. Its this statement that I think is the problem: 'Now, I assume operating with an array of matrices would be much faster'.  Where do you base that assumption? I can split/ apply over a list and very easily speed up a process via `snowfall` and `foreach`. I haven't seen an argument as to why processing over an array of matrices would be faster than processing over a list of matrices.

Comment: @Rui Barradas You're right thanks, I've changed my code acccordingly, though it was just to illustrate the stuff to be done later.

Comment: @SeldomSeenSlim I thought I pointed the argument in my second comment, list = 3Ddataframe, array = 3Dmatrix.

Comment: I believe `abind` in the abind package will create the arrays, but I agree with the other commenters that list + lapply and maybe parallel processing will probably be faster and easier.  If you get the array and the list versions working, I'd love to see a speed comparison.

Comment: @JakeFisher: Having dealt with introducing parallel processing on raster format data, I would say save yourself some time and just take a hammer to your thumb now, then figure out a solution that lets you do the work over a list. Although it *can* be done, introducing parallel processing over an array is exceedingly difficult. Unless you have a need information in a neighborhood manner, ie a smoothing function that takes the focal mean of a raster cell based on a [3,3,N] array where N = number of bands in the raster, the raster being an [X,Y] matrix.

Comment: @jaySf Well just address the question: Why do you think operating on an array of matrices would be faster than operating on a list of matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enough with the hooha. Lets time it.

```
library(microbenchmark)
# matrix generating function
mxSim <- function(X, n) {
  mx = matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = 3, 
              dimnames = list(NULL, c("d", "alpha", "beta")))
  mx[,1] = rbinom(n, 1, .375)
  mx[,2] = rnorm(n, 0, 2)
  mx[,3] = .42 * rnorm(n, 0, 6)
  return(mx)
}

# bundle matrices together
mx.lst <- lapply(1:1e1, mxSim, n = 1e4)

mx.array <- array(mx.lst,dim=c(2,5))
# some stuff to be done after, like e. g.:

#Timing...
some.fnc<-function(m)lm(d ~ alpha + beta, as.data.frame(m))

list.test<-microbenchmark(lapply(mx.lst, some.fnc))

array.test<-microbenchmark(apply(mx.array, MARGIN=c(1,2), some.fnc))
 expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 lapply: 74.8953 101.9424 173.8733 146.7186 234.7577 397.2494   100
 apply:  77.2362 101.0338 174.4178 137.153  264.6854 418.7297   100
```

Naively applying a function over a list as opposed to an array is almost identical in actual performance.

Comment: I repeated this revealing bench with 1e3 matrices and got a mean of 9.83 : 9.99 seconds. So the apply version is actually 1.6 % slower.

Comment: Perhaps you may have a look at the bench in second answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness I just made some other benchmarks with n=1e3 as stated in the comment of @SeldomSeenSlim's answer. In addition I made it with a list of `data.frames()`, and this was a bit surprising.

Here is the function for `data.frames`, for matrix function see above.

```
dfSim <- function(X, n) {
  d <- rbinom(n, 1, .375)
  alpha <- rnorm(n, 0, 2)
  beta <- .42 * rnorm(n, 0, 6)
  data.frame(d, alpha, beta)
}
```

Bundeling

```
mx.lst <- lapply(1:1e3, mxSim, n = 1e4)
mx.array <- array(mx.lst, dim = c(2, 500))
df.lst <- lapply(1:1e3, dfSim, n = 1e4)
```

And the microbenchmarks:

```
some.fnc <- function(m) lm(d ~ alpha + beta, as.data.frame(m))
list.test <- microbenchmark(lapply(mx.lst, some.fnc))
array.test <- microbenchmark(apply(mx.array, MARGIN = c(1, 2), some.fnc))
df.list.test <- microbenchmark(lapply(df.lst, some.fnc))
```

Results

```
Unit: seconds
expr            min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
lapply     9.658568 9.742613 9.831577 9.784711 9.911466 10.30035   100
apply      9.727057 9.951213 9.994986 10.00614 10.06847 10.22178   100
lapply(df) 9.121293 9.229912 9.286592 9.277967 9.327829 10.12548   100
```

Now, what does us tell this?

But, okay, as a bold sidenote:

```
microbenchmark((lapply(1:1e3, mxSim, n = 1e4)), (lapply(1:1e3, dfSim, n = 1e4)))
           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
(lapply(mxSim)) 2.533466 2.551199 2.563864 2.555421 2.559234 2.693383   100  a 
(lapply(dfSim)) 2.676869 2.695826 2.718454 2.701161 2.706249 3.293431   100   b
```

Comment: Hmmm. Sehr interessant... So does this tell us that its more-so about how we're wrapping the functions? My guess from these results is that (and we do know some of this)  is that when we apply over an array of matrices, that  it is internally listing them (to reduce dimensionality to 1). Hence the DF/lapply has less overhead. But then why wouldnt the lapply/ matrix be faster, assuming the lapply/DF solution has to convert the DF to a mtrx?